# Shell routing issue on back button when passing page ID

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I am receiving the following error on Android only (fine on iOS)

> Shell: Failed to Navigate Back: System.ArgumentException: Ambiguous routes matched for: //D_FAULT_FlyoutItem12/IMPL_homepage/homepage/indexpage/indexpage

I declare the page like so in AppShell

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("indexpage", typeof(Pages.Index));
```

Because the content of the page is dynamic, I navigate to it like so

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"indexpage?indexid={clicked.ID}");
```

This works fine when going to an index page from a list

However, when I get to the index page and then go to another page of a different type, also via the route registered in AppShell, but again by passing in an ID, and then try and go back, I get the error

Again, the error only occurs on Android - iOS works fine

Comment: the last paragraph description is not clear, could you clarify by reformulating and including some code from AppShell.xaml and Appshell.xaml.cs about the pages structure/hierarchy and routes definitions ?

Comment: @Cfun I thought I had done? The Routing code above is from AppShell.xaml.cs, and the GoToAsync is from a later page which uses the reference registered to go to a page template and use the ID to load content. I wonder if the issue is with 'chaining' these events? Because the 'back' button works fine on both platforms when going to indexpage from a list page, but when going to another page using that ID the error gets presented

Comment: I meant that a minimal relevant code (not one line and not a book at the same time) makes the question more clear than describing the code.

Answer (score 2):

or anyone that will face this issue, and have this error message too;

```
 System.ArgumentException: 'Ambiguous routes matched for: ...'
```

This occures when you register your routes in XAML (in the appshell file) and you also try registering your routes in code behind in C#. Only register your routes once using either XAML or C# not both.

to fix your error: most likely you have a page register 2 times... 1st time register in AppShell.xaml.cs file and 2nd time register in AppShell.xaml.

just remove double register and it should work. good luck

Comment: This was the answer for me. I was registering in code-behind and xaml and missed that.  Thanks.